# How to read file that is on some specific IP address from any webdomain or local system using java?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have one program that runs on a specific `IP` and put output in a file on same system.
I want to read that file from other system or domain(web) using ajax and jquery from jsp page.

I am getting error of `cross browser origin not allowed`.

How do I resolve this error to make cross browser ajax request?

thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: If I specified datatype as jsonp, do I need to add callback function?

Comment: Yes you do . as well on server side also .

Comment: How do I define it @serverside??

Comment: see my answer below. I have explained everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can’t query domain B via ajax on domain A's page. 

javascript load is allowed as an exception. (We are loading fb and twitter js the same way)

Workaround:

Jquery has provided method getJSON which expects a js return from server. All we need to do is to pass 

a '?' as a parameter value. In following case, 

we are passing 'callback' parameter with value '?'

$.getJSON('http://www.otherserver.com/somedestination.htm?callback=?','firstname=Jeff',function(res){

 alert('logged in: '+res.some_text);

 });

For this call, JQuery will call server as: 

http://www.otherserver.com/somedestination.htm?

callback=jQuery16200023653062526136637_1386745308424&firstname=Jeff&_=1386745308439

Now if we look closely, the value for '?' is : jQuery16200023653062526136637_1386745308424.

JQuery creates a global JS function in window DOM named 

jQuery16200023653062526136637_1386745308424(response)

At server we extract this parameter (callback) and make a function String. In this function we will pass 

the value we want to return to the Browser: 

out.print(request.getparameter("callback")({'some_text' : '23897932823sdfhsdkfvhs32432'})

This will return 

 jQuery16200023653062526136637_1386745308424(({'some_text' : 'value of the text output'}) 

 to the browser

Jquery will execute this function and will pass the string to our getJSON function parameter.
```

Comment: How do I handle callback on .java page?? or there is no need to handle it?? You have specified it in solution but I am getting error on  line out.println(req..)......